# mysql sort field increment value with extra grouping

Tags: php, mysql

I have corrupted sort_order field that needs to be corrected by updating the rows to be in incremental order. When there are no groupings, this solution works great:

```
SET @i := 0;
UPDATE tbl SET sort_order= @i:=@i+1 ORDER BY sort_order;
```

But when you're talking about a table that requires the sort_order field to reset for each group, that solution fails. In my case, unique groups are a composite of user and type, so the sort_order should reset for each unique user/type combo.

What could I do to update this:

```
id      user    type    name    sort_order
152070  cust    forex   ^EURUSD 3
374143  cust    forex   ^EURGBP 3
376218  cust    stock   IBM     3
376219  cust    stock   FB      3
376219  cust    stock   AMZN    3
374676  degr    forex   ^BTCUSD 3
376217  degr    forex   ^AUDJPY 3
376220  degr    stock   C       3
376221  degr    stock   AMZN    3
```

To look like this:

```
id      user    type    name    sort_order
152070  cust    forex   ^EURUSD 1
374143  cust    forex   ^EURGBP 2
376218  cust    stock   IBM     1
376219  cust    stock   FB      2
376219  cust    stock   AMZN    3
374676  degr    forex   ^BTCUSD 1
376217  degr    forex   ^AUDJPY 2
376220  degr    stock   C       1
376221  degr    stock   AMZN    2
```

I'm also open to a PHP solution.

EDIT:

MySql 5.6

The first solution I posted results in this, which is not the desired result. Again, I want to sorting to be reset per group.

```
id      user    type    name    sort_order
152070  cust    forex   ^EURUSD 1
374143  cust    forex   ^EURGBP 2
376218  cust    stock   IBM     3
376219  cust    stock   FB      4
376219  cust    stock   AMZN    5
374676  degr    forex   ^BTCUSD 6
376217  degr    forex   ^AUDJPY 7
376220  degr    stock   C       8
376221  degr    stock   AMZN    9
```

Comment: waht do you mean with fail? ... you have an error .. show error message, wrong result  ?  show your actual result , you expected  result and explain the logi for the result

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: @scaisEdge Edited my question to show the result of the first solution.

Comment: @P.Salmon mysql 5.6

Comment: I don't get the group(s) you are numbering by - the first 2 rows for example don't appear to be duplicates so why do they get a sort_order of 1 ,2

Comment: How many variants of `user` and `type` do you have?

Comment: @P.Salmon Sorry if this is confusing. Picture a unique index on user,type,sort_order. So each user has multiple types, and the sort_order should reset for each unique user/type.

Comment: @Samir Thousands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are loads of answers on this site relating to row number simulation and here's another which is used in a multi-table update.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id  int ,   user varchar(20) ,  type varchar(20) ,  name varchar(20),   sort_order int);
insert into t values
(152070 , 'cust'  ,  'forex' ,  '^EURUSD' ,3),
(374143 , 'cust'  ,  'forex' ,  '^EURGBP' ,3),
(376218 , 'cust'  ,  'stock' ,  'IBM'     ,3),
(376219 , 'cust'  ,  'stock' ,  'FB'      ,3),
(376219 , 'cust'  ,  'stock' ,  'AMZN'    ,3),
(374676 , 'degr'  ,  'forex' ,  '^BTCUSD' ,3),
(376217 , 'degr'  ,  'forex' ,  '^AUDJPY' ,3),
(376220 , 'degr'  ,  'stock' ,  'C'       ,3),
(376221 , 'degr'  ,  'stock' ,  'AMZN'    ,3);

update t join
(select t.*,
        if(concat(user,type) <> @p, @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rownumber,
        @p:= concat(user,type) p
from t
cross join (select @rn:=0,@p:='') r
order by user,type,id) s
on s.id = t.id
set t.sort_order = s.rownumber
;
select * from t;

--------+------+-------+---------+------------+
| id     | user | type  | name    | sort_order |
+--------+------+-------+---------+------------+
| 152070 | cust | forex | ^EURUSD |          1 |
| 374143 | cust | forex | ^EURGBP |          2 |
| 376218 | cust | stock | IBM     |          1 |
| 376219 | cust | stock | FB      |          3 |
| 376219 | cust | stock | AMZN    |          3 |
| 374676 | degr | forex | ^BTCUSD |          1 |
| 376217 | degr | forex | ^AUDJPY |          2 |
| 376220 | degr | stock | C       |          1 |
| 376221 | degr | stock | AMZN    |          2 |
+--------+------+-------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! And even fast on a table with hundreds of thousands of rows. Definitely beyond what I could have come up with on my own.